# How to return rooms resource using Microsoft graph api in office365

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Am trying to test an API call using Microsoft graph api explorer to return all rooms resource configured in my tenant. The endpoint call returns empty list.

Below is the call endpoint as per microsoft documentation.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$select=displayName, emailAddress
```

microsoft doc [article describing the call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Response am getting.
[image]

permission assigned
[image]

rooms configured in the tenant
[image]

The rooms are not hidden from GAL
[image]

What could be causing rooms not to be returned?

Comment: Maybe your rooms are defined as group of rooms. Could you try https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.roomlist ?

Comment: It returns empty list as well.

Comment: There is a note in the documentation that `Rooms that are marked "Hidden from GAL (Global Address List)" can't be retrieved through this endpoint.` Not sure if it's your case. How did you create rooms?

Comment: i created from office365 admin center portal. its shown in the screenshot inside the question. Please check the question have added a screenshot showing the room is not hidden in the GAL.

Comment: When did you create the rooms? Because it can take 24-48h for the rooms to show up.

Comment: Thank you Selmir, i just noticed that. After creating the rooms i have to wait 48hours before executing the api call.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: After creating the rooms mailboxes in the tenant, there is a 48 to 72hours wait window before the API requests works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).